# kernel parameter - net.core.netdev_max_backlog , what happened when its too low

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel, hadoop, sysctl

we want to understand what are the aspects when `net.core.netdev_max_backlog`  kernel value is very low and not as recommended

on our Linux RHEL machines , the value for this parameter is `1000`

since our machines are HADOOP machines ( BIGDATA cluster )

we saw that best practice is to increase the value to `65536`

as describe on:

https://datasayans.wordpress.com/2015/11/04/performance-kernel-tuning-for-hadoop-environment/

background:

The kernel parameter “netdev_max_backlog” is the maximum size of the receive queue. The received frames will be stored in this queue after taking them from the ring buffer on the NIC. Use high value for high speed cards to prevent loosing packets. In real time application like SIP router, long queue must  be assigned with high speed CPU otherwise the data in the queue will be out of date (old).

**so -  what could be the aspects when this kernel parameter is with un-Insufficient value ?**

other - reference - https://gist.github.com/leosouzadias/e37cd189794bb78de502ac25cb605576

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/OS-Configurations-for-Better-Hadoop-Performance/ta-p/247300

https://www.senia.org/2016/02/28/hadoop-and-redhat-system-tuning-etcsysctl-conf/

https://mapredit.blogspot.com/2014/11/hadoop-server-performance-tuning.html

https://gist.github.com/phaneesh/38b3d80b38cc76abb1d010f598fbc90a

https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configRecommendedSettings.html

PDF - https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/solutions/collateral/data-center-virtualization/big-data/cloudera-intel-cisco-hadoop-benchmark.pdf

Comment: BLUFF: If the value is to small packets will be dropped.

Comment: how to verify if small p are dropped?

Comment: Instead of providing a ton of reference links you should focus on the question's clarity.  It definitely needs some work on that front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could the effects be when this kernel parameter value is insufficient

Run the following command:

```
for i in {1..30}; do date; cat /proc/net/softnet_stat; sleep 1; done
```

The following will be the output:

```
001c1216 000000b0 00000040 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
02fdffa5 000000aa 00000032 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

**02fdffa5** is the packet count
**000000aa** is the number of packets that have been dropped

Run the command and see if the amount of packets that have been dropped has increased by converting the value to decimal.  If the number of packets has increased then increase `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` to an appropriate value.

You can temporarily increase the value by running the following command:

```
sysctl -w net.core.netdev_max_backlog=2000
```

You can make the value permanent by running the following command:

```
echo "net.core.netdev_max_backlog = X" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Additionally, a value of 65536 is excessive and unnecessary for proper system performance.  **You should obviously change `X` to the value you wish to use.**

If the second and third column of softnet_stat is not growing then it's necessary to increase `net.core.netdev_max_backlog`

Source: [How to tune `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` and `net.core.netdev_budget` sysctl kernel tunables?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1241943)

Comment: I have summarized the RHEL article to the best of my ability.  Since RHEL requires a subscription to use, any real licensed user of RHEL, should be able to access the article.  If it was a little short I would attempt to capture an image of it to argument my answer.