# net.core.netdev_max_backlog - what's the impact when set too HIGH?

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, syslog, splunk

I'm working on optimizing and right-sizing my EC2 syslog-ng servers and have some carryover settings in our ansible playbook for kernel settings that were used on "in-house" data center machines.  (Previosly we also used syslog-ng in the DC, whereas now we are using [SC4S](https://splunk.github.io/splunk-connect-for-syslog/main/))

Related to `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` specifically:

Redhat portal states the default is 1000, but we're currently setting it to 65536, and I don't have any records of why or where that recommendation came from.

I've found lots of helpful articles here and on the Redhat portal about testing and increasing this setting, but **what is the impact of this being set too high?**

[kernel parameter - net.core.netdev_max_backlog , what happened when its too low](https://superuser.com/questions/1718366/kernel-parameter-net-core-netdev-max-backlog-what-happened-when-its-too-low/1718371#1718371?newreg=a95566c541364e81a660abb5bcaaa5f8)

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1241943

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It relates to the maximum amount of backlog. This a higher value creates a larger log, and a larger log will cause a slight slowdown for creating the log and a larger filesize.

Comment: this may be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3923785/4418

Comment: see also https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/scaling.html "
Flow limit is useful on systems with many concurrent connections, where a single connection taking up 50% of a CPU indicates a problem. In such environments, enable the feature on all CPUs that handle network rx interrupts (as set in /proc/irq/N/smp_affinity).

The feature depends on the input packet queue length to exceed the flow limit threshold (50%) + the flow history length (256). Setting net.core.netdev_max_backlog to either 1000 or 10000 performed well in experiments.
"